# Does the Eclipse Communication Framework (ECF) require an OSGI container or can it run w/out?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-ecf

I recently heard a podcast from the Eclipse people and there was interesting attributes/ abilities discussed about ECF.

I have not been able to find a definitive article in the online documentation that discusses the required runtime. It seems from examining the way downloads are listed that everything is packaged as a OSGI bundle.

Can anyone confirm that whether an OSGI container is required or will the framework function in a plain old JVM.

Are there any gotchas or requirements...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not what you wanted to hear, but ECF definitely needs to be running in an OSGi container.  See http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/NewAndNoteworthy.html under the section on ECF4Felix.  Some type of OSGi container will always be required, as this is an implementation of OSGi 4.2 RSA.

Comment: Im not sure if my original travels found that page, perhaps it was as the text is not exactly definitive. It says it uses certain OSGI services but does not explicitly say they that a container is required. I wanted verification as i was hoping at the very least to simulate the OSGI container interfaces if possible but wanted some commentary to help decide if i should attempt the impossible.

Comment: The container is a very unique environment, and really redefines some of the basics that people take for granted like classloading.  I would recommend against attempting the impossible here, but honestly there's nothing saying you couldn't simply include the Equinox OSGi container and do it that way.  It may not be as daunting as it sounds.  What is your current environment?

Comment: My original q was hoping that the key ECF components could be instantiaated by code outside a container. If any required an OSGI container component then i would supply a working version. Classloading schemantics though different are not an issue if one is happy to lose the visibility boundaries that an osgi container creates for non exported classses for a pariticular bundle. Regarding the last item i dont care about the hiding aspect that an osgi container provides so after all that there should be no real problem.